# Configuring Varnish On Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, caching, varnish

I have trouble with my magento Varnish configuration on Ubuntu 16.04
I get 502 error on my site. My configurations are below.. Could someone help me?

**/etc/apache2/ports.conf:**

```
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 7081
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 7081
</IfModule>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
```

**/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service:**

```
Type=simple
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=82000
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secr
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/reload-vcl
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true
```

**/etc/varnish/default.vcl:**

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}
```

**/etc/default/varnish:**

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
         -T localhost:6082 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
         -s malloc,256m"
```

Comment: I need advice on this as well if you managed to solve it. 3 hours later I am beginning to think maybe varnish is not at all reading the /etc/default/varnish settings.